# Define connection strings in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to sharepoint. I'm trying to connect to a SQL Database inside a sharepoint webpart using **SPSqlDataSource**. Code is working well. But I need to set the **connectionstring** without refering to the **web.config**

Is there a way to define it in a variable kind of thing in sharepoint, so that user can define the connectionstring in the UI without editing the **web.config** file. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it for every WebPart, you could do a [Web Part with a custom Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

For example:

```
    [WebBrowsable(true),
    WebDisplayName("Connectionstring"),
    WebDescription("The connectionstring."),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
    Category("YourCategory"),
    DefaultValue("")]
    public string Connectionstring { get; set; }
```

It will show as a SharePoint-Option.
But i think there are better solutions out there, because you will have to set it for every WebPart and the user needs the permissions for editing webparts.

Comment: Thanx... Didn't know about custom properties earlier... This works fine.